# Why not auto move if object is destroyed in next step?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

If a function return a value like this:

```
std::string foo() {
  std::string ret {"Test"};
  return ret;
}
```

The compiler is allowed to move ret, since it is not used anymore. This doesn't hold for cases like this:

```
void foo (std::string str) {
  // do sth. with str
}

int main() {
  std::string a {"Test"};
  foo(a);
}
```

Although `a` is obviously not needed anymore since it is destroyed in the next step you have to do:

```
int main() {
  std::string a {"Test"};
  foo(std::move(a));
}
```

Why? In my opinion, this is unnecessarily complicated, since rvalues and move semantic are hard to understand especially for beginners. So it would be great if you wouldn't have to care in standard cases but benefit from move semantic anyway (like with return values and temporaries). It is also    annoying to have to look at the class definition to discover if a class is  move-enabled and benefits from `std::move` at all (or use `std::move` anyway in the hope that it will sometimes be helpfull. It is also error-prone if you work on existing code:

```
int main() {
  std::string a {"Test"};
  foo(std::move(a));

  // [...] 100 lines of code
  // new line:
  foo(a); // Ups!
}
```

The compiler knows better if an object is no longer used used. `std::move` everywhere is also verbose and reduces readability.

Comment: The compiler isn't generally "allowed" anything in particular. It has to implement the rules of the language, and the rules of the language say how overload resolution works in the case of `return ret`. (An actual thing that the compiler truly *is* allowed is to not use any constructors at all for the return.)

Comment: did you turn on compiler optimizations?

Comment: `std::move` also works if a class doesn't have move semantics. It just does nothing. So you can freely use it when you know you are using an object for the last time.

Comment: @Giulio Franco I know but I think to use it like this  this is cumbersome, verbose and error-prone.

Comment: in your case, shouldn't it better to do `void foo(std::string& string)` ? I think different features have different appropriate usage. And obviously what you are doing is a unnecessary misuse of move.  You simply shouldn't do `std::move(a)` if you know `a` is going to be used later

Comment: @Adrian Shum foo is only a trivial example for a function that needs a an movable class by value. This is sometimes useful .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not obvious that an object is not going to be used after a given point.
For instance, have a look at the following variant of your code:

```
struct Bar {
  ~Bar() { std::cout << str.size() << std::endl; }
  std::string& str;
}

Bar make_bar(std::string& str) {
  return Bar{ str };
}

void foo (std::string str) {
  // do sth. with str
}

int main() {
  std::string a {"Test"};
  Bar b = make_bar(a);
  foo(std::move(a));
}
```

This code would break, because the string `a` is put in an invalid state by the move operation, but Bar is holding a reference to it, and will try to use it when it's destroyed, which happens *after* the `foo` call.

If `make_bar` is defined in an external assembly (e.g. a DLL/so), the compiler has no way, when compiling `Bar b = make_bar(a);`, of telling if b is holding a reference to `a` or not. So, even if `foo(a)` is the last usage of `a`, that doesn't mean it's safe to use move semantics, because some other object might be holding a reference to `a` as a consequence of *previous* instructions.

Only **you** can know if you can use move semantics or not, by looking at the specifications of the functions you call.

On the other side, you can always use move semantics in the `return` case, because that object will go out of scope anyway, which means any object holding a reference to it will result in undefined behaviour regardless of the move semantics.
By the way, you don't even need move semantics there, because of copy elision.

Comment: Obviously, this code is dubious. You should not make objects hold references to other objects so lightmindedly.

Comment: It seems to be a common point of confusion that move semantics optimises returning local variables from a function. As you say return value optimisation and copy elision have been around for a long time.

Comment: @sjdowling actually, from what I've seen, copy elision is usually faster than move.

Comment: In general, the difficulty is directly linked to the fact that C++ gives you the choice between value and reference semantics. It will go away if you give up with one of the two. If you only use references, all your objects are `shared_ptr`s, and you never have to use move, because copying a reference is almost as expensive as moving it. If you never use references, then you know the scenario of my example can never happen, and can freely move (but there's no way of telling the compiler to disallow references to a given type, you have to do it by means of documentation)

Comment: I'm not completely sold on your Argument,  that other objects might hold a reference to it. A compiler can an does track, if the address of an object was taken or not.

Comment: @sjdowling: Yes and no. While rvo is more efficient than move, it is not guaranteed to happen, so you could say that move semantics improve the worst case behavior of returning complex Objects.

Comment: @MikeMB as I said, the compiler can have no prior knowledge if `make_bar` is an external symbol. Also, you can fool the compiler by means of pointer arithmetics.

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated a bit more: As soon as the address of an object has been taken, the compiler should of course not be allowed to auto-move that object anymore. The same is true for class members and arrays, however none of this applies to the original example of TNA.  In my opinion, it would be possible to change the standard accordingly without breaking code, but it would be far too much specification effort for far too little benefit and it would btw. also introduce context dependent overload resolution, which (luckily) doesn't exist in c++.

Comment: @MikeMB that would require checking all pointers at run time, and counting references to each object. That's something C++ doesn't do and will probably never do by default: its philosophy is that you don't pay what you don't use. You can, of course, implement it as an opt-in feature, which is what `shared_ptr` already does, or you can implement some more specific reference-like class. What you're asking would require the compiler to check every pointer returned from an external library against all live objects, that's insanely expensive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73318/discussion-between-giulio-franco-and-mikemb).

Answer (score 1):

Its all sums up on what you define by "Destroyed"? std::string has no special effect for self-destroying but deallocating the char array which hides inside.

what if my destructor DOES something special? for example - doing some important logging? then by simply "moving it because it's not needed anymore" I miss some special behavior that the destructor might do.

Comment: Actually, deallocation does something special because it calls `delete` which alters global state of memory allocation. This is why it is not pure and cannot be optimized away.

Comment: my point was that the destructor has other features other the deallocation , what it usually does .

Answer (score 0):

Because compilers cannot do optimizations that change behavior of the program except when allowed by the standard. `return` optimization is allowed in certain cases but this optimization is not allowed for method calls. By changing the behavior, it would skip calling copy constructor and destructor which can have side effects (they are not required to be pure) but by skipping them, these side effects won't happen and therefore the behavior would be changed.

(Note that this highly depends on what you try to pass and, in this case, STL implementation. In cases where all code is available at the time of compilation, the compiler may determine both copy constructor and destructor are pure and optimize them out.)

Comment: Yes, this is not  allowed by the Standard. The Question is why? The compiler knows if a class is  is trivially destructible http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_trivially_destructible/

Comment: `std::string` is not trivially destructible

Comment: Yes but this is only an example.

Comment: In cases where the type is trivially copy-constructible and trivially destructible, `std::move` is a no-op and therefore the call can be thought as being optimized (because the optimization would do nothing).

Answer (score 0):

While the compiler is allowed to move ret in your first snippet, it might also do a copy/move elision and construct it directly into the stack of the caller.
This is why it is not recommended to write the function like this:

```
std::string foo() {
    auto ret = std::string("Test");

    return std::move(ret);
}
```

Now for the second snippet, your string a is a lvalue. Move semantics only apply to rvalue-references, which obtained by returning a temporary, unnamed object, or casting a lvalue. The latter is exactly what std::move does.

```
std::string GetString();

auto s = GetString();

// s is a lvalue, use std::move to cast it to rvalue-ref to force move semantics
foo(s);

// GetString returns a temporary object, which is a rvalue-ref and move semantics apply automatically
foo(GetString());
```

Comment: Your last example isn't a universal reference but a simple rvalue reference.  Also what do you mean with breaking "the overloading of function parameters"?

Comment: You are right, it's only an universal reference if the argument type is deduced, which in this not the case in my example. In the case the argument type was deduced, there would be two different functions which might have bound to the value, but the complete example is moot without the universal reference, so I removed it.